# Access the “Back” button in the browser using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, browser, web-scraping

I am wondering if there is a simple function that can access the “Back” button in the browser. Basically I need to step through several links on a single page and rather than just opening them all up at once I want to click one line, get info from it and then go back to the previous page and select the next link. Any ideas?

I currently have no code at all to even begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The InternetExplorer.Application object has a GoBack method that should do what you want.

[The Internet Explorer Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970456.aspx)